# SQL Function - This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression

Tags: sql-server

```
CREATE TABLE Property542
(
    PID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL ,
    PropertyID AS RIGHT ('PID0000' + CAST(PID AS VARCHAR(10)), 10) PERSISTED 
          CONSTRAINT PK_Property PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
    Availability BIT NOT NULL,
    P_Address VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    MonthlyRent INT NOT NULL,
    Max_tenants INT NOT NULL,
    Type_of_Property VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    --NIC varchar(10) FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Landlord (NIC)
)

CREATE TABLE DetachedHouse768
(
    PropertyID VARCHAR(10) PRIMARY KEY,
    Dept VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
)

DECLARE @id TABLE (ID varchar(10))

INSERT INTO Property542
OUTPUT INSERTED.PropertyID INTO @id(ID)
VALUES (1, 'Kandy Road,Pasyala', 5000, 4, 'DetachedHouse'),
       (0, 'Kale para,Mathara', 7500, 2, 'Flat'),
       (1, 'No34,New Town,Kaluthara', 10000, 1, 'TerransedHouse');

INSERT INTO DetachedHouse768(PropertyID, Dept) 
VALUES ((SELECT ID FROM @id), 'room'),
       ((SELECT ID FROM @id), 'floor'),
       ((SELECT ID FROM @id), 'House');
```

I get this error:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression. The statement has been terminated.

I want to insert more data in onetime using this method.

Comment: And the error tells you the problem. What about the error don't you understand, so we can try to elaborate (though it is quite explicit).

Comment: I can't understand how to fix it.

Comment: Well, which value of `ID` are you expecting for each row? Expected results would help us help you.

Comment: It seems like you expect each use of `(SELECT ID FROM @ID)` to return the value from just one of the rows created by the previous section in sequence. That is **NOT** what would happen. Each use would return _all three rows_ created in the previous section, meaning which value to use for these new inserts is **ambiguous** (not well defined).

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO DetachedHouse768(PropertyID, Dept) 
select i.ID, d.dept
from @id as i
cross join (values('room'), ('floor'), ('House')) as d(dept);
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your intent to insert 3 `DetachedHouse768` rows (room,floor,house) for each previously inserted Property542 row, the primary on DetachedHouse768 is incorrect. `PropertyID` alone is not unique so it mist be a composite key on both `PropertyID` and `Dept` to be unique.

Below is an INSERT...SELECT example with `CROSS JOIN`:

```
CREATE TABLE Property542
(
    PID int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL ,
    PropertyID  AS RIGHT ('PID0000' + CAST(PID AS VARCHAR(10)), 10) PERSISTED 
          CONSTRAINT PK_Property PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
    Availability bit NOT null,
    P_Address varchar(30) Not null,
    MonthlyRent int Not null,
    Max_tenants  int Not null,
    Type_of_Property varchar(15) Not null
);

CREATE TABLE DetachedHouse768
(
    PropertyID varchar(10),
    Dept varchar(30) Not null,
    CONSTRAINT PK_DetachedHouse768 PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED(PropertyID,Dept)
);

DECLARE @id TABLE (ID varchar(10))
INSERT INTO Property542
OUTPUT INSERTED.PropertyID INTO @id(ID)
VALUES  (1,'Kandy Road,Pasyala',5000,4,'DetachedHouse')
       ,(0,' Kale para,Mathara',7500,2,'Flat')
       ,(1,'No34,New Town,Kaluthara',10000,1,'TerransedHouse');
INSERT INTO DetachedHouse768( PropertyID ,Dept)
SELECT ID, Dept
FROM @id
CROSS JOIN (VALUES
     ('room')
    ,('floor')
    ,('house')
) AS Depts(Dept);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `SELECT ID FROM @id` in your 2nd `INSERT` statement is not deterministic, meaning it doesn't return only 1 value.

In that part of the query (the sub-query), it is expecting only 1 value, and your `SELECT ID FROM @id` doesn't do that (obviously) because of lacking conditions you can set using `WHERE` clause.